# MySQL: How to import 50th column from a CSV file?

Tags: mysql, csv, import

Let's say I have a CSV file with 100 columns.  How do I import only the 50th column?  Here's my code so far:

```
DROP TABLE temp;

CREATE TABLE temp
(ID          INT               AUTO_INCREMENT          primary key,
 sn           VARCHAR(50)
);

DESCRIBE temp;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/...temp.csv' INTO TABLE temp
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@null,  @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,
 @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,
 @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,
 @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,
 @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,
 @null,  @null,  @null,  @null,  @col50)
set sn=@col50;

SELECT * FROM temp;
```

This does get the job done, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This seems like a reasonable approach to me - i can't think of a better way.

Comment: Hmmm. okay. thanks.  I was trying to avoid using @null so many times by miscounting or something like that.  Thanks though!

Comment: Well,  I guess there are techniques for processing CSV files outside of SQL.

Comment: Using Python or something like that?

Comment: Yes, that kind of thing.

Comment: It doesn't have to be `@null`, it could be `@anything`... the advantage of `@n` would be improved readability. You might also wish to format the code into blocks of five or ten codes per line, rather than 50 on one line.

Comment: Another approach would be to look at shell scripts and regular expressions... I believe your pattern is "maybe something then a comma" 49 times, followed by what you want, followed by another "maybe something then a commas", then end-of-line (\n or \r\n depending on OS).

Comment: There are also a number of command-line tools to query CSV files with SQL. Example: http://harelba.github.io/q/ or https://github.com/koppen/csv_query or others. You could use one of those tools to extract the 50th column by name (names are typically defined in the header line of the CSV file), and save that to a new file. Then it's a lot simpler to LOAD DATA INFILE from the resulting new file that contains only the column(s) you need.